# FFmpeg issue with special char "@" in png file name

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, special-characters

I just discovered an issue with ffmpeg when trying to create an mp4 video file from multiple png files that contain @ in the file name.

So I'm calling

```
ffmpeg_exe -y -f concat -i temp@temp.mp4.txt -safe 0 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p temp@temp.mp4
```

The content of the txt file is multiple line such below:

```
file 'temp@temp-1.png'
duration 0.2
file 'temp@temp-2.png'
duration 0.2
file 'temp@temp-3.png'
duration 0.2
file 'temp@temp-4.png'
duration 0.2
```

The issue comes from the "@" in the file names. If I remove the @ from the file names and accordignly from the txt file, it works.

Has @ a special meaning for ffmpeg. How can I escape it?

Thanks

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Quoting-and-escaping and http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/quoting-and-escaping.htm.gz may help for starting points

Answer (score 1):

After looking this a bit, as you suspected, there is an issue with the `@`. This is because of this part in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-44) where the `@` is considered unsafe (*not being part of the letters, digits, period, underscore, and hyphen character set*)

> 20.5.2 Options
> This demuxer accepts the following option:
>
> safe
> If set to 1, reject unsafe file paths and
> directives. A file path is considered safe >if it does not contain a protocol >specification and is relative and all >components only contain characters from the >portable character set (letters, digits, >period, underscore and hyphen) and have no >period at the beginning of a component.
>
> If set to 0, any file name is accepted.
>
> The default is 1.

The filename(s) having `@` requires the `-safe 0` directive, which you included.

However, the **`-safe 0`** needs to go before the `-i temp@temp.mp4.txt`. The ordering is important because ffmpeg will automatically keep the **-safe default of 1** due to how ffmpeg evaluates ordinally the options for the demuxer and the file(s) to be worked on.

Here's some example output running the command with strace. You'll notice the `@` after concat seems to be used to address specific memory, so I believe that is why it is considered unsafe within ffmpeg.

**with `-safe 0` in the wrong spot:**

```
write(2, "\33[48;5;0m\33[38;5;207m[concat @ 0x"..., 50[concat @ 0x55f7ac3063c0] ) = 50
write(2, "\33[48;5;0m\33[38;5;196mUnsafe file "..., 82Unsafe file name 'temp@temp-1.png'
```

**with `-safe 0` before `-i`:**

```
write(2, "\33[48;5;0m\33[38;5;207m[concat @ 0x"..., 50[concat @ 0x5600e673a3c0] ) = 50
write(2, "\33[48;5;0m\33[38;5;226mDTS 144 < 86"..., 53DTS 144 < 86016
```

***And finally, I was able to run your incantation successfully by placing the `-safe 0` before the `-i` (tested on Linux)***

```
$ ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i temp@temp.mp4.txt -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p temp@temp.mp4
```

Comment: You may explain the purpose of `-safe 0` beyond the recipe.  Relative filenames are supposed to be "safe" according the [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate). And here the "`@`" is likely the reason why `-safe 0` is needed ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029574/14778592))

Comment: @PierU thanks for the nudging. I updated it some.